# User reputations using Facebook's Like or similar service?

Tags: facebook, service

I have a custom comment system in website, and want to integrate user reputations into it.

Any way to have something similar to Facebook's Like button, but that would also display user reputations calculated from Likes?

I'd like to avoid implementing user reputations myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [irkoo](http://irkoo.com), this is generic service for user reputations. The drawback is that it stores all the reputation data on its servers (much like Facebook though). But that makes it easier to integrate.